# Generator problem for reduced group C*-algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

(Not sure if it is appropriate or not, if no I will delete the post)

Recently I am concerned about the number of generator of $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{k})$, the reduced group algebra of the free group, generated by k generators. In this presentation([link](http://hannesthiel.org/wp-content/slides/2021_06-GeneratorRank.pdf)), in slide 5, the author mentioned that it is an open problem to determine if $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{k})$ is singly generated for $k\geq2$.

The question I want to ask is, isn't $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{k})$ has at least $k$ generators? If I understand correctly, let $\mathbb{C}G$ denote the group algebra of $\mathbb{F}_{k}$, this is dense subalgebra in $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{k})$. Let $\delta_{g}$ be the indicator function of group element $g$. Then for generators $x_{1},...x_{k}$, the algebra generated by $\delta_{x_{1}},...\delta_{x_{k}}$ is the $\mathbb{C}G$. Now since each $\delta_{x_{i}}$ is algebraically independent, the number of generators is at least $k$. What mistakes did I make in the above?

Comment: There is no proper subset of $\{\delta_{x_1}, \ldots, \delta_{x_k}\}$ that generates, but that does not mean there couldn't be another generating set with fewer elements.

Comment: To further illustrate @NikWeaver's point: the non-unital Cstar algebra $c_0$ is singly generated, in the sense that we can find $f\in c_0$ such that the closed subalgebra generated by $f$ is all of $c_0$. (One can take $f(n)= 2^{-n}$.)

Comment: Take $C^{*}_{r}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ as an example, if it is singly generated, shouldn't the $\delta_{x}$ and $\delta_{y}$ have some algebraic relation, or $\delta_{y}$ equal to infinite sum of power of $\delta_{x}$?

Comment: Belated reply: no, because in this setting the word "generates"  means "topologically generates", so it is conceivable that there could be some mixture of delta_x's and delta_y's, call it f, such that combinations of powers of f could approximate delta_x  to within arbitrary accuracy.